# Display phtml file result in header

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, header

using languages.phtml code we are displaying different stores result as below :

[image]

we are trying to add languages.phtml file result after 3 icons in header [here](http://stylebaby.com/).

[image]

but when i placed below code , its not working

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setTemplate('page
/switch/languages.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>
```

file is present in `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/page/switch/languages.phtml`

**header.phtml**

```
    <div id="header">
<header id="header" class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-container">
        <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrcSmall() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="small" />
        </a>

        <div id='hideshow'><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/search_16.png');?>" alt="Search">


        </div>



        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setTemplate('page/switch/languages.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>

        <?php // In order for the language switcher to display next to logo on smaller viewports, it will be moved here.
              // See app.js for details ?>
        <div class="store-language-container"></div>

        <!-- Skip Links -->

        <div class="skip-links">
            <a href="#header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Menu'); ?></span>
            </a>

            <a href="#header-search" class="skip-link skip-search" id="hideshow1">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Search'); ?></span>
            </a>

            <div class="account-cart-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <!-- <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span> -->
                </a>


                <!-- Cart -->

                <div class="header-minicart">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

        <!-- Navigation -->

        <div id="header-nav" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Search -->

        <div id="header-search" class="skip-content desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Account -->

        <div id="header-account" class="skip-content">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--<div id="header-search" class="desktop-only">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        </div>-->
</header>


<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/switch')->setTemplate('page
/switch/languages.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>
```

Note: Changed Block type to `page/switch`

Also try: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>` in `header.phtml`

Comment: same result after i used : `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>` please check code and help me.

Comment: your link is not working